# A question about camera vertical rotation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

In the model, the camera rotates horizontally around the Z-axis (THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1)). When rotating vertically, how to determine the rotation vector?
I want to calculate the rotated '**newTarget**', but always fails.

---

```
var camera = viewer.navigation.getCamera();
var horizontalRadians = (horizontalAngle * Math.PI) / 180;
var verticalRadians = (verticalAngle * Math.PI) / 180;

// Compute the vector from position to target
var direction = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(camera.target.clone(), camera.position.clone()).normalize();

// vertical
var verticalQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z), verticalRadians);
direction.applyQuaternion(verticalQuaternion);

// horizontal
var horizontalQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), horizontalRadians);
direction.applyQuaternion(horizontalQuaternion);

var newTarget = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(camera.position.clone(), direction);
console.log(newTarget)
```

How can I modify this code or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the initial and new state of the viewer and get the difference between the respective eye and the target objects.
[image]